# IS vs AS keywords for PL/SQL Oracle Function or Procedure Creation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been trying to find out what the difference is between the `IS` and `AS` keywords in PL/SQL when creating an Oracle function or procedure.

I have searched and have been unable to find any information on this. Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: They're semantically identical, as far as I'm aware

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I've never known there to be a difference.  The [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm) implies that they are synonyms:

> The function body begins with the keyword `IS` (or `AS`) and ends with the keyword END followed by an optional function name.

Answer (score 20):

Same as DISTINCT and UNIQUE in select statements.
i.e, there is no material difference between 'IS' and 'AS'.
Backwards compatibility and meeting standards

Comment: Why does IS return only one row in a package procedure using SYS_REFCURSOR, while AS returns all rows?