# is versus as pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, semantics

I thought that oracle treats both "is" and "as" same for functions and procedures.I tried googling with "pl/sql is vs as" and got the following link which says both are the same.

[IS vs AS keywords for PL/SQL Oracle Function or Procedure Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338408/is-vs-as-keywords-for-pl-sql-oracle-function-or-procedure-creation)

But I found http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/declaration.html#index_by which seems to indicate there is a difference. Could somebody (list/point me to a link) the other contexts where using "is/as" makes a difference?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By example (not all are PL/SQL):

```
[CREATE] PROCEDURE x IS|AS ...
[CREATE] FUNCTION x IS|AS ...
CREATE PACKAGE [BODY] x IS|AS ...
CREATE TYPE [BODY] x IS|AS ...

CURSOR x IS ...
TYPE x IS ...
SUBTYPE x IS ...

CREATE TABLE x AS subquery
SELECT x AS "y" FROM z AS "w"
WITH x AS (SELECT ...
```

Therefore, `AS` is not always allowed where `IS` is, and `IS` is not always allowed where `AS` is :)

Just one of those quirks of the language, I think. Generally, `IS` is more common, I think, except where `AS` is the only option (as in the SQL examples above). Most of the examples in the Oracle docs seem to use `IS`, and personally that's my preference as it fits better semantically, in my opinion.

References:

[Oracle SQL Reference 11gR1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm)

[Oracle PL/SQL Reference 11gR1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm)

Comment: +1 for the confusing explanation ;-)

Comment: Or as Bill Clinton once observed, "it depends on what the meaning of the word 'is' is" :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4XT-l-_3y0

Comment: 'Therefore, AS is not always allowed where IS is, and IS is not always allowed where AS is' +1 for brilliant sentence :)